# UILabel Not Displaying Mutliline

Tags: label

Trying to display the text of the UILabel in three different lines:

First Line

Second Line

Third Line

But is showing up in single line "First Line Second Line Third Line"

Can the label display multiple lines?

Comment: What language/framework?

Comment: web/windows ?? what is the platform?

Comment: I'm betting he means a label in a GUI such as a JLabel in java.  The simple answer if that is the case is to use html in the string that is getting set.  For example: setText("<html>First Line<br>Second Line<br>Third Line");

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking about form labels in HTML?

You can add line breaks after each part, or you can wrap each "line" as a span. I think anything else may be invalid.

example:

```
 <label for="some_input">First Line<br />Second Line<br />Third Line<br /></label>
 <input id="some_input" type="checkbox" name="input1" />
```

Or:

```
 <label for="some_input"><span>First Line<\span><span>Second Line<\span><span>Third Line<\span></label>
 <input id="some_input" type="checkbox" name="input1" />
```

then add the CSS:

```
 label span {
     display: block;
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using this lable in the gridview. on row data bound i am replacing chr(10) and chr(13) WITH